# sentiment analysis to find top 3 adjectives for products in tweets

Tags: data-mining, sentiment-analysis, apriori

there is a sentiment analysis tool to find out people's perception on social network.
This tool can:
(1) Decompose a document into a set of sentences.

(2) Decompose each sentence into a set of words, and perform filtering such that only
product name and adjectives are preserved.

e.g. "This MacBook is awesome. Sony is better than Macbook."

After processing, We can get:

{MacBook, awesome}

{Sony, better}. (not the truth :D)

We just assume there exists a list of product names, P, that we will ever
care, and there exist a list of adjectives, A, that we will ever care.

My questions are:

1. Can we reduce this problem into a specialized association rule mining
   problem and how? If yes, anything need to be noticed like reduction, parameter
   settings (minsup and minconf), additional constraints, and modication to the
   Aprior algorithm to solve the problem.
2. Any way to artificially spam the result like adding "horrible" to the top 1 adjective? And any good ways to prevent this spam?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you just copy paste your homework problem here, and then add "Thank you!" :/?

Comment: Which language will be using?

Comment: Ben: Sorry. Read some papers regarding sentiment analysis, and they all mentioned about aprior algo. But still confusing about modification to Aprior.
Mishra: Just logic would be enough

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered **counting**?

For every product, *count* how often each adjective occurs.

Report the top-3 adjectives for each product.

Takes just *one* pass over your data, and does not use a lot of memory (unless you have millions of products to track).

There is no reason to use association rule mining. Association rule mining only pays off when you are looking for *large itemsets* (i.e. 4 or more terms) *and* they are equally important. If you know that one term is special (e.g. product name vs. adjectives), it makes sense to split the data set by this unique key, and then use counting.